# Create Badges using WinForms Reporting

Tags: winforms, reporting

I have been strugling with the creation of a simple report. Attached the picture of what I want to create, could someone give me some guide? I have managed to create a half page badge, but how to create another column?[image: This uses a third party, but I am pretty sure it can be done with WinReports]

Comment: You can do it comfortable using Crystal reports, it is much easier compared to that

Comment: Could you guide me somehow on this, I don't mind using Crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is from [FastReport.Net](https://www.fast-report.com/en/products/FastReport.Net.html) demo as I see.

To set two column view select "Data Band",  go to "Properties" window and open the "Columns" property, set the "Count" property to 2.